# Moving window multivariate linear regression (R) (similar to multivariate version of lqd.filter)

Tags: r, regression

I need to do a moving window linear regression of a multivariate dataset.  I have played with lqd.filter() and similar in package "robfilter" which is the sort of thing I am after, but I need to include the x variable as it is not a constant.  Have I missed another package which allows you to do this?

Example dataframe, where x=Year and y=Value.  If it could include the errors (for y) that would be ideal, but its not critical.

```
    structure(list(Year = c(1950L, 1923L, 1920L, 1907L, 1896L, 1865L, 
    1845L, 1822L, 1796L, 1754L, 1732L, 1708L, 1654L, 1613L, 1548L
    ), Value = c(-0.8, -0.5, -0.3, 0.4, 0.3, -0.2, -0.6, -0.7, -0.9, 
    -1, -0.7, -0.8, -1.2, -1.4, -1.6), Error = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2)), .Names = c("Year", 
    "Value", "Error"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

I am aiming for something like a 50 year moving window; and an output regression value for each moving window that I can then plot up as a curve (against other similar datasets).

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You may have a look at `rollapply` in the `zoo` package. On the help pages you find examples of rolling regression.

Comment: Thanks Henrik.  I have been having a play with it and it looks like the right idea, though at the moment am struggling to get it to work with my data, but think that is just me being an idiot!  Cheers.

Comment: Henrik - am I being daft, but will zoo work with this type of time series data, as it doesn't seem to be like the types of time-series examples I have seen?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by 'this type'. What have you tried?